# django reference to an entire table, not to a specific entry

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently working on a setting system. here i create settings for the display of different models.
I'm just missing an efficient reference to the model/table.
With the foregnkey you can set a reference to a specific instance, but I'm looking for a reference to an entire table.

I'm currently doing it via a charfield, but find it inefficient. is there some kind of modelField?

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass


class B(models.Model):
    pass


class C(models.Model):
    pass
```

> Classes A, B and C are any datastores for which I want to store settings.

```
class foo(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     classname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
     #parameters of settings
```

> Blockquote
> foo is the class in which I want to store the settings for the other classes

I read the settings, but there it is definitely more efficient:

```
   settingsA = foo.objects.filter(user=user, classname = A.__name__)
   settingsB = foo.objects.filter(user=user, classname = B.__name__)
   settingsC = foo.objects.filter(user=user, classname = C.__name__)
```